# Flutter app DRAWER that can be displayed on all my pages

Tags: flutter, dart

I would like to know if there is a better way of doing this:
I want a drawer that opens up with a menu(List view and list tiles) that can be used to navigate my app, log out and change the language. The drawer drops down from a menu icon prefixed on the appbar (automatically)

I already made the drawer and it works. I coded it into the settings page, BUT I want this drawer/icon to be available on all the pages (once you've signed in)

My "noob solution" is to copy and paste the drawer code on all the pages, but I know there is a better way of doing it, I just can't remember what it is or how to do it. I know this is basic but it's got me stuck and I don't know how to google it, is it how to create a method? a function? a custom widget? a private method?

Can someone please help with this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just create a dedicated widget (stateful or stateless) and place all of your drawer's code into that widget. Then you can instantiate that widget every time you need it.

```
class AppDrawer extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  _AppDrawerState createState() => _AppDrawerState();

}

class _AppDrawerState extends State<AppDrawer> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     // your drawer's code
  }
}
```

And then in some other widget where you need your drawer:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) => Scaffold(
    appBar: [...]
    drawer: AppDrawer(),
    body: [...]
);
```

Comment: Thank you. Took me a while to implement it correctly but I did it. Created a new class (statefull widget) That class returned a drawer (with all my code for that drawer)
I made an instance of it on other pages by coding:

drawer: AppDrawer(),

Just under the app bar code and above the body code. 

It seems to work fine. Thank again!

Kind regard,

Answer (score 0):

There may be a better approach but here is how I did mine.

This is my main dashboard that contains the drawer

```
 return Scaffold(
          drawer: Drawer(
            key: Key("dash_board_screen_key"),
            child: menu(context: context, model: model),
          ),
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text(
              model.getTitle(),
            ),

            centerTitle: true,
            actions: <Widget>[
              IconButton(
                  icon: Icon(
                    Icons.lightbulb_outline,
                    size: 18,
                  ),
                  onPressed: () {
                    model.toggleDarkMode();
                  }),
            ],
          ),
          body: Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20.w, right: 20.w),
            child: Expanded(child: getDashboardWidget(model)),
          ) // dashboard(context),
        );
```

as you can see above, the **getDashboardWidget** returns a widget that is displayed

```
 Widget getDashboardWidget(DashboardController model){

    switch (model.selectedItem) {
      case DashboardMenu.cart:
        return CartScreen();

     

      case DashboardMenu.notification:
        return NotificationScreen();

      case DashboardMenu.profile:
        return ProfileScreen();
    }

    return CartScreen();
  }
```

so depending on whatever drawer option was selected, i updated only the body of the dashboard page.

This means that all other screens(CartScreen, Notification) share the same scaffold.